# Tengo un problema para hacer un programa de rifa en Java

Tags: javascript

Se que es facil, pero soy nuevo en esto, queria empezar a hacer un programa que entre 30 numeros seleccione uno de ellos, y que si algun participante tiene ese numero (se genera aleatoriamente) pues gana, ademas de listar en pantalla todos los números de la rifa. Los números disponibles
deben aparecer como tales, mientras que para los que ya se vendieron
deben mostrarse también los datos de los participantes que los
compraron.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? Tienes claro que Java y Javascript son lenguajes diferentes? Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).